# Unmarshal XML where soap envelope is a child element, using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, marshalling

I want to deserialize the following XML using JAXB:

```
<testData>
    <tx>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                      xmlns:ns="http://my/namespace">
            <soapenv:Header>
               ...
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body>
                ...
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
   </tx>

   <flag>true</flag>
   <someObject>
      ...
   </someObject>
</testData>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to represent a soap envelope in the Java model to deserialize it successfully. 
This is the input data of tool made for our testers and envelope is going to be copied from SOAP UI.

The only solution I came up with is to use `@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)` and have the envelope as an object in the model, which eventually will be deserialized to `ElementNSImpl`. But it doesn't look like the best solution.

How can I solve this problem? Suggestions to change format are welcome too, as long as they will allow to conveniently store(in one file) and deserialize copy-pasted soap envelope and additional objects I have added in the example XML.

This is my Java model at the moment:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "testData")
public class XMLWrapper {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private Object tx;
    private boolean flag;
    private SomeObject SomeObject;
}
```

And unmarshalling:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLWrapper.class);
jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new File("file.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you declared for the XML element `<tx>` a property with type `Object`,
JAXB did not have enough information to create anything more specific than `ElementNSImpl`.

You will need a better Java model for the `<tx>` element.
Instead of declaring it as type `Object`

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
private Object tx;
```

you need to declare it with a full-featured Java class (let's call it `Tx`):

```
private Tx tx;
```

The class `Tx` represents the XML element `<tx>` and everything nested inside.
It can look like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Tx {

    @XmlElement(name = "Envelope", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    private SoapEnvelope envelope;
}
```

For modeling the XML element `<soapenv:Envelope ...>` you declare a property
(let's call it `SoapEnvelope envelope`). This property needs to be annotated
with [`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html) to tell JAXB it maps to the XML element name `Envelope`.
Notice especially its `namespace` parameter which corresponds to the XML namespace definition
`xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`.

Then repeat the same procedure with the `SoapEnvelope` class
for modeling the contents within the XML element `<soapenv:Envelope>`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SoapEnvelope {

    @XmlElement(name = "Header", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    private SoapHeader header;

    @XmlElement(name = "Body", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    private SoapBody body;
}
```

Then repeat the same procedure with the `SoapHeader` and `SoapBody` classes
for modeling the contents within the XML elements `<soapenv:Header>` and `<soapenv:Body>`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SoapHeader {
    ...
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SoapBody {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It actually works, thank you. But I faced another problem using this approach: there might be different objects inside the body of the message. So the problem is that I have to create SoapBody class for each type of object (I can't simply make it generic since I also have to change name and namespace in the @XmlElement, can I?) and it leads to creating multiple SoapEnvelope classes as well. Is there a workaround for this case?

Comment: I don't know anything about SOAP. so I'm not sure I understood this problem correctly. May be you can within the `SoapBody` class solve this polymorphism problem by using
[`@XmlElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html). See the example given there.